# Retrieve a value from MongoDB and set a string to it in Python(Pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I am trying to retrieve a value from MongoDB and set a string to it in Python with MongoDB. Here is my user registration function:

```
def registerAccount():
    registerUsername = input('Please input a username to be registered into our database.')


      registerPassword = input('Please input a password to be entered into our database.')
        passwordHash = sha256_crypt.hash(registerPassword)

        regDetails = {
            "username": registerUsername,
            "passwordhash": passwordHash
        }

        db = client.pinnacle
        users = db.users
        users.insert(regDetails)
```

and here is my login function:

```
def login():
    db = client.pinnacle
    users = db.users

    pwHash = users.find_one({"passwordhash"})
    print(str(pwHash))

    loginUsername = input('Please input username to be signed in.')
    loginPassword = input('Please input password to be signed in.')
    # pprint.pprint(users.find_one({"username": "1"}))

    # example = users.find_one({"username": "1"})

    pbkdf2_sha256.verify(loginPassword, pwHash)
```

Basically, I need to search the database for the username, and get the string right after the username which is passwordHash. Then I will set pwHash to that string which will be checked with PassLib. Help is appreciated. Thanks!
Also if anyone is interested you can see my full code [here](https://hastebin.com/ajokoconuc.py).

Comment: You mean `user = users.find_one({ "userName": loginUsername })` and then `pbkdf2_sha256.verify(loginPassword, user['passwordhash'])`. Where of course you actually only "retrieve" from the database once you have the `loginUsername` input supplied. Otherwise you don't know which data you are actually getting.

Comment: @NeilLunn hey man, appreciate the help. I added that to my script and am now getting a different error. Details here because wouldn't fit in a comment: https://hastebin.com/enekadehiw.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this happens whenever i select to login, even after not typing in username or password

The error is caused by this line below:

```
pwHash = users.find_one({"passwordhash"})
```

Where you should specify a filter of key/value pair, instead it's only specifying a key. You should remove the line above (and the `print` line right after it). See also [pymongo find_one()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method for more info.

Also, in the same function `login()`, you have a typo for key `username`.

```
user = users.find_one({"userName": loginUsername})
```

Note that it should be lowercase `username` to be consistent with how you're storing them elsewhere in the code.

Lastly, you should replace

```
pbkdf2_sha256.verify(loginPassword, user['passwordhash'])
```

with below method, as this is how you encrypt it in the `registerAccount()`

```
sha256_crypt.verify(loginPassword, user['passwordhash'])
```

Please consider adding error checks throughout your code. i.e. if `users.find_one()` returns `None` do `XYZ`.